# How to update the date column and increase the counter?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I have to increase the counter and update the updated_at column. I used following code to increase the counter based on the click but I am not sure how to update date column.

```
Link::where('role', $id)->increment('counter');
```

Comment: I think `update_at' column automatically update, when you update the data in the table.

Comment: @TharakaDilshan oh yes . i just noticed it is auto updated

Comment: Yes, the column automatically updates.

Answer (score 2):

It should be the default value of updated_at is ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

```
`updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

Or,

```
`updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```